# Mount home from different disk (migrating from ubuntu)

Tags: nixos

I am moving from ubuntu to nixos. I would like to keep my previous home directory which is on another disk.

I installed nixos successfully. Then I added

```
fileSystems."/home" = {
  device= "/dev/disk/by-uuid/123...;
  fsType = "ext4";
};
```

to `configuration.nix`, which seems to mount the disk correctly.

However, **I cannot login to kde** with my user anymore. It is

```
users.users.manuel = {
  isNormalUser = true;
  uid = 1000; # all files in /home/manuel have uid 1000
  home=/home/manuel;
  extraGroups = [ "wheel" "networkmanager ];
};
```

The group does not match:

```
> ll /home
drwxr-rxr-x 55 manuel 1000 4.0K Mar 7 16:58 manuel/
```

The user can login into console and also write into `/home/manuel`. But its home `~` is at `/nix/store/1gr0...-manuel`.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Use a string (not path) value for the `users.users.manuel.home` attribute.

`home = "/home/manuel";`

Nix has a native path type. A path literal like `/home/manuel` gets built into an immutable package and the resulting read-only nix store path is used as the value. This is useful for including source files in packages, but not what you need here. Instead, use a string literal like `"/home/manuel"`.